# Finding Lowest Price in Woocommerce Cart Items

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

Wondering if anyone can help me resolve my problem here. I am looking for a way to apply a coupon code to a Single (least expensive) product item in a Cart. e.g. customer add 2 SG bats at price of 100 and 200 respectively.

I want to apply 30% coupon code to my first bat (rs 100 X .70 = 70 price) for the first bat since its a cheapest item in the cart. So customer will pay 270 rs for total purchase.

I have tried to add this coupon on the Woo commerce by product but it applies to all the products (300 X .70 = 210 price).

I tried different functions of Cart object to retrieve the each item pricing without any success.

```
 global $woocommerce;
    $lowestPrice=1000;
    $myproduct_price=0;

foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {
   $myproduct_price=$value['data']->price;
if($myproduct_price < $lowerPrice) $lowestprice=$myproduct_price;
}
```

this code is giving me error.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there are 2 steps:

1. Get all cart product's price and store in one array
2. find minimum value from array

Complete Code: (Tested)

```
global $woocommerce;

if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) { 
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $product_price[] = get_option('woocommerce_tax_display_cart') == 'excl' ? $_product->get_price_excluding_tax() : $_product->get_price_including_tax(); /*Store all product price from cart items in Array */
    }
}
$lowestprice = min($product_price); // Lowest Price from array
```

Hope it will help you :)